# 18.04 install on ESXI6.7 SQUASHFS error

Tags: system-installation

While installing 18.04 (and 19.04 for that matter) get SQUASHFS error with bad sectors referencing.  Originally, I got boot BIOS/EFI mismatch error which I corrected by changing boot option for VM in ESXI to EFI. Tried installing 19.04, it was getting stuck on NTP sync for some reason and failing.  Now trying with 18.04 and getting the this SQUASH error.  I have EVE-NG running as a VM on the same datastore and I checked every disk with Victoria from Hiren's before creating RAID for the datastore.  Can someone please help?

[SQUASHFSerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stCNH.png)

Comment: Squashfs errors imply either your download was imperfect (did you verify it), OR your write to install media was faulty (did you check it?)  Possible useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Answer (score 0):

Your install media is faulty.

Either you had a

- bad download (did you verify your ISO, ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 ),

OR

- your write to media failed (did you check it post-write? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)

The 'check disc for defects' refers to the install-media, not your hdd/ssd's, and yes some references (eg. wiki) refer to any install media as a CD (even if thumb-drive, magnetic-tape, dvd or actually a CD)

Comment: thank you for that, you are absolutely correct. As you can see above, I went a different route.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ISO was corrupt.  I downloaded from website directly.  A friend suggested to get one from bittorrent and it worked.

Comment: Downloading via bittorrent just repeats the download step, and doesn't ensure you have a legit download or perfect download, or the write to media was valid.  The steps I outline should still be performed.  Yes torrent's may ensure what you downloaded was what you were supposed to get, but was the torrent an official one? or did it verify you have the corrupted-mitm-attacked version, and does address a faulty-write-to-media flaw.

Comment: I appreciate pointing that.  I am checking the hash values from now on.